# Why does my GET request using PHP cURL return a blank page?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to run a GET request with PHP and cURL.

Below is my original code (taken from Postman and slightly edited, the Postman app returns the API request as expected):

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://xxx.yyy.zzz",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "apiPassword: password"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
print_r($response);


?>
```

The website uses a header password to identify which APIs I have access to.

When I run the php page on my server, it returns a blank page.

**Things I have tried:**

Adding an error check:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://xxx.yyy.zzz",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "apiPassword: password"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}

curl_close($curl);
print_r($response);


?>
```

The response is with the error check added is the single line of text, no error code is displayed to assist with fault finding:

> Curl error:

Adding getinfo for cURL:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://xxx.yyy.zzz",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "apiPassword: password"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
echo "</br>";
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));

curl_close($curl);
print_r($response);


?>
```

The response:

> Curl error:
>
> Array ( [url] => http://xxx.yyy.zzz
>   [content_type] => [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size]
>   => 0 [filetime] => -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0 [namelookup_time] => 2.9E-5 [connect_time] => 0
>   [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0
>   [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] =>
>   -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => [certinfo] =>
>   Array ( ) [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0)

Trying to cURL Google:

I tried to see if it may be the website which is having issues, so I changed the URL to Google and I received the same responses as above:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "http://www.google.com",
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

if(curl_errno($curl)){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
echo "</br>";
print_r(curl_getinfo($curl));

curl_close($curl);
print_r($response);


?>
```

The response:

> Curl error:
>
> Array ( [url] => http://www.google.com/ [content_type] =>
>   [http_code] => 0 [header_size] => 0 [request_size] => 0 [filetime] =>
>   -1 [ssl_verify_result] => 0 [redirect_count] => 0 [total_time] => 0.001668 [namelookup_time] => 0.001726 [connect_time] => 0 [pretransfer_time] => 0 [size_upload] => 0 [size_download] => 0
>   [speed_download] => 0 [speed_upload] => 0 [download_content_length] =>
>   -1 [upload_content_length] => -1 [starttransfer_time] => 0 [redirect_time] => 0 [redirect_url] => [primary_ip] => [certinfo] =>
>   Array ( ) [primary_port] => 0 [local_ip] => [local_port] => 0 )

Does anyone have any idea why the cURL is not working? Am I missing something?

TIA

Comment: For interests sake, if I bash a cURL request: `curl http://www.google.com`, from the same server, i get a response.

Answer (score 0):

Anybody else running in to the issues I had, I managed to get it resolved:

I changed

```
if(curl_errno($curl)){
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($curl);
}
```

to

```
if($errno = curl_errno($curl)) {
    $error_message = curl_strerror($errno);
    echo "cURL error ({$errno}):\n {$error_message}";
}
```

This actually gave me the error code and description, which allowed me to identify the problem. I was getting a connection error. (7)

I had to enable httpd on SELinux

```
setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on
```

Working as expected now.